# How to Handle a great number of rows with SQL Queries and take only small amount of data efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm coding a site in PHP, and site will contain really much messages(like 100.000 , 200.000 or more) which users will post on the site. The problem is, messages will be stored on a table called 'site_messages' by it's ID. This means, all messages aren't grouped by their poster, it's grouped by their ID. If I want to fetch the messages that are posted by user 'foo', I have to query a lot of rows, and it will get really slow I think. Or I want to fetch the messages by post subject(yes, it will contain post subject column too, and maybe more column to add), I must query all the table again, and unfortunately, it will be less efficient. Is there any speedy solutions about that? I'm using PHP and MySQL(and PHPMyAdmin).

**Edit:** For example, my table would look like this:

---

MessageID: 1

MessageContent(Varchar, this is the message that user posts): Hi I like this site. Bye!

MessagePoster(Varchar): crazyuser

MessagePostDate: 12/12/09

MessagePostedIn(Varchar, this is the post subject): How to make a pizza

---

MessageID: 2

MessageContent(Varchar): This site reallllly sucks.

MessagePoster(Varchar): top_lel

MessagePostDate: 12/12/09

MessagePostedIn(Varchar): Hello, I have a question!

---

MessageID: 3

MessageContent(Varchar): Who is the admin of this site?

MessagePoster(Varchar): creepy2000

MessagePostDate: 1/13/10

MessagePostedIn(Varchar): This site is boring.

---

etc...

Comment: Sorry, how do you know which message belongs to which poster

Comment: You're going to have to be much more specific about your data columns, tables, relationships, etc. for anyone to provide help... Example data and expected outcomes will also help.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us some desensitised sample data.

Comment: I don't completely understand the question and agree with SQLTactics. Anyway 200k shouldn't be a problem if you write decent queries, unless you try to join tables by values extracted from strings or other crazy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is what DBs (especially relationship DBs) were built for! MySql and other DBs use things like indexes to help you get access to the rows you need in the most efficient way. You will be able to write queries like `select * from site_messages where subject like "News%" order by entryDateTime desc limit 10` to find the latest ten messages starting with "News", or `select * from site_messages, user where user.userid='foo' and site_messages.fk_user=user.id` to find all posts for a certain user, and you'll find it performs pretty well. For these, you'd probably have (amongst others) an index for the subject column, and an index on the fk_user column.

Work on having a good table structure (data model). Of course if you have issues you can research DB performance and the topic of `explain` plans to help.

Yes, for each set of columns you want, you will query the table again. Think of a query as a set of rows. Avoid sending large numbers of rows over connections.  As the other commenters have suggested, we can't help much more without more details about your tables.

Comment: I edited my post. Is it useful now? By the way, It's the first time I've seen that second SQL syntax. Normally, I would fetch data from another table with inner join, but this solution is better I think.

Comment: You'll be fine doing queries off that. Use indexes (e.g. `alter table site_messages add index posterIX (messagePoster ASC)`) if you are going to be using that column a lot in joins or where clauses. The inner join or `where ... and` styles are equivalent, it is just a preference. Good luck.

Comment: The 'second syntax' is just an old fashioned way of writing `select * from site_messages INNER JOIN user ON site_messages.fk_user=user.id where user.userid='foo'`.

Answer (score 1):

Two candidates for indexing that jump right out are (Poster, PostDate) and (PostDate, Poster) to help queries in the form:

```
select  ...
from    ...
where   Poster = @PID and PostDate > @Yesterday;
```

and

```
select  Poster, count(*) as Postings, ...
from    ...
where   PostDate > @Yesterday
group by Poster;
```

and

```
select  Poster, ...
from    ...
where   PostDate between @DayBeforeYesterday and @Yesterday;
```

Just keep in mind that indexing improves queries at the expense of the DML operations (insert, update, delete). If the query/DML ratio is very low, you just may want to live with the slower queries.